# trigger click on div style which don't contain id

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, greasemonkey

trigger click on div if viewed hide it..

**DIV**

```
`<div style="background-color: transparent;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #10bece 0%, #0c8d99 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#10bece, #0c8d99);
background-repeat: repeat;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-size: auto auto;text-overflow:hidden;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;padding:2px;padding-left:3px;padding-right:3px;width:190px;border-radius:3px 3px 0 0;"><a href="./view.php?i=4435" target="_blank" style="text-overflow: ellipsis;overflow: hidden;white-space: nowrap;font-weight: normal;font-size: 13px;height: 17px;line-height: 17px;color: #FFF;">Join ooo</a></div>`
```

**HTML**

```
<table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td style="font-size:11px;color:#666;padding:1px;border-top:1px dashed green;padding-top:3px;"><td style="width:60%">&<b>0.0~0.02</b></td><td align="right"></td></tr></tbody></table></td>
```

**code sample**

```
$('.style="color:#666').click();
```

Comment: `style` is not a class.. Also note that attribute selector looks for exact match for `value`, not subset of `value`

Comment: it don't have any class

Comment: You dont have any div too.. Where you want the click to happen?

Comment: @ramlokesh Div added

Comment: @jhonde :  question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is something tricky with **[`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/)**

```
$('[style]').filter(function() {
  $(this).attr('style').indexOf('color:#666') > -1;
}).click();
```

---

or with **[attribute contains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)**

```
$('[style*="color:#666"]').click();
```

---

**FYI :** If you are searching for `td` then use `$('td[style...` or in case it's `div` then use `$('div[style...` otherwise it may select other element with same inline style property.

Comment: May want to change your outer selector to `'div[style]'`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek :  I don't think that he wants to select div, since it doesn't have the specific style.... anyway lets wait for his response :)

Comment: They do mention *"trigger click on div style"*, so I'm assuming they mean on the `div`, but yes it's not exactly clear.

Comment: @PranavCBalan open url i want bot to click on ptc and if viewed hide it

Comment: @jhonde It's not clear if you mean the `div` or the `td`, do you want to trigger the click event on the `div` element?

Comment: @jhonde :  pleas be more clear... that which div do you want to be clicked ? and based on which value that we can select it ?

Comment: its fine where to add eq(1) in this $('[style*="color:#666"]').click();
 ??

Comment: @jhonde `$('[style*="color:#666"]').eq(0).click();`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").each(function(){ //or td
 if($(this).attr("style").indexOf("color:#666") >= 0){
  $(this).trigger("click");
}
})
```

This is not an elegant solution but should work

Answer (score 0):

```
<td onclick="showData1()" style="font-size:11px;color:#666;padding:1px;border-top:1px dashed green;padding-top:3px;"><table width="100%"><tbody><tr><td style="width:60%">&<b>0.0~0.02</b></td><td align="right"></td></tr></tbody></table></td>

    window.showData1=function ()
    {
        alert("");
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the OP is looking into how to select a element based on their `style`, and triggering their click event. Rather than adding a click event to an element.

Answer (score 0):

you can select element by style like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('td[style*="color:#666;"]').on("click", function(){
    $(this).css("border-color","red");
  });

  $('td[style*="color:#666;"]').click();
});
```

I create example in jsfiddle, you can try this
[JsFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/pajarft/fkyLx65f/)

Comment: its fine where to add eq(1) ??

Comment: $('td[style*="color:#666"]').eq(0).click();